# How to get last frame's pose relative to base frame

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if `tf` is capable of providing the pose (position and orientation) of the last frame in the tree relative to the base frame in the same tree? Also, does `tf` use Denavit Hartenberg to establish the forward kinematic tree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401564/how-to-get-last-frame%27s-pose-relative-to-base-frame/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you mean with 'the last'. With a lot of tf trees, there is not 1 last link.

As for getting the pose of the link relative to the base_link, that's what `tf listeners` are for. The tutorials:

1. [tf listener C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)
2. [tf listener Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29)
3. [tf2 listener C++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)
4. [tf2 listener Python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29)

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By this question and its replies there: https://answers.ros.org/question/300789/denavit-hartenberg-dh-to-urdfsdf-or-tf-tf2/ I assume no standard DH for this forward kinematic, but it's not so sure.

You may find KDL documentation useful for this kind of calculations: http://wiki.ros.org/kdl and https://www.orocos.org/kdl.html

> What can I use KDL for?
>
> 1. 3D frame and vector transformations: KDL includes
>    excellent support to work with
>    vectors, points, frame
>    transformations, etc. You can
>    calculate a vector product, transform
>    a point into a different reference
>    frame, or even change the reference
>    point of a 6d twist. For more
>    information take a look at the
>    geometry documentation on the KDL
>    homepage.
> 2. Kinematics and Dynamics of kinematic chains: You can represent a
>    kinematic chain by a KDL Chain object,
>    and use KDL solvers to compute
>    anything from forward position
>    kinematics, to inverse dynamics. For
>    more information take a look at the
>    chain documentation on the KDL
>    homepage.The kdl_parser includes
>    support to construct a KDL chain from
>    a XML Robot Description Format (URDF)
>    file.
> 3. Kinematics of kinematic trees: You can represent a kinematic chain by a
>    KDL Chain object, and use KDL solvers
>    to compute forward position
>    kinematics. Currently no other solvers
>    are provided.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1